# Unstable, seed-dependent training with ~4 distinct patterns

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, gmm

I am trying to replicate a paper, but I am having trouble with unstable training. More precisely, rerunning the code yields wildly different results. However, I think that there are 4 main patterns.

The model and the training are as shown below (full code at https://www.kaggle.com/code/adelphene/dagmm):

```py
class DAGMM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim=118, latent_dim=1, n_gmm=4):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 60), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(60, 30), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(30, 10), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(10, latent_dim),
        )

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(latent_dim, 10), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(10, 30), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(30, 60), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(60, input_dim),
        )

        self.estimator = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(latent_dim + 2, 10), nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(10, n_gmm), nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        l = self.encoder(x)
        r = self.decoder(l)

        re = (x - r).norm(p=2, dim=1) / x.norm(p=2, dim=1)
        cs = F.cosine_similarity(x, r, dim=1)
        z = torch.cat((l, re.unsqueeze(-1), cs.unsqueeze(-1)), dim=1)

        g = self.estimator(z)

        return r, z, g

# ------------------------------------------------------

torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(False)

epochs = 200
lr = 1e-4

loss_fn = Loss()
batches = len(train_dataloader)
model = DAGMM(n_gmm=4).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch, (x, _) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        r, z, g = model.train()(x)
        loss, _ = loss_fn(x, r, z, g)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 400 == 0:
            r, z, g = model.eval()(val_dataset.x)
            val_loss, e = loss_fn(val_dataset.x, r, z, g)
            threshold = np.percentile(e.detach().cpu(), 80)
            y_pred = (e > threshold) * 1
            y_true = val_dataset.y
            report = classification_report(y_true.cpu(), y_pred.cpu(), output_dict=True)
            a = round(report["accuracy"], 2)
            p = round(report["macro avg"]["precision"], 2)
            r = round(report["macro avg"]["recall"], 2)
            print(f"loss: {round(loss.item(), 3)}, accuracy: {a}, precision: {p}, recall: {r} [{batch+1}/{batches}] [{epoch+1}/{epochs}]")
```

To be clear, the number of epochs, the optimizer, and the learning rate are taken directly from the paper.

The patterns that I get are as follows:

1. Loss decreases to 0.5/0.6/0.7, the accuracy is ~0.88, and precision and recall are both ~0.82
2. Loss stuck at ~2.0, accuracy ~0.6, precision and recall ~0.44
3. Loss between ~1.5 and ~0.8, accuracy between ~0.75 and ~0.85, precision and recall between ~0.65 and ~0.75
4. (Best) Accuracy goes down to ~1.2/~0.8, accuracy goes up to ~0.94, and precision and recall to ~0.92

I am not exactly sure how I should approach this. Any guidance is appreciated!

PS: I believe that I observer pattern 2 more often than the others.

Comment: Have you tried the code directly from the author (including training and data processing, e.t.c.) to see if the issue happen? IMHO, I think with unsupervised learning, the result can vary vastly due to initialization. (I'm not familiar with unsupervised learning though)

Comment: @MinhNguyenHoang the paper doesn't point to a publically available code